# When would I use ant for Java web development?

Tags: java, web-applications, ant

I do not understand the purpose of ant.  I read the introduction, but am missing the big picture.  I know the following (or at least that I want to use them),

Java
jdbc
hibernate
jsp
servlet container like Tomcat

But I don't see how ant fits in.

Is there some all comprehensive tutorial that tells me how to put all this together?

Why would I want ant?  What is the alternative if I don't have ant?

EDIT:  So is this sort of the compiling part of its Visual Studio counterpart?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ant is used as a build system.  You do not have to use it--in fact there are quite a few better systems but since ant was one of the first it's still likely to be very common.  It generally is used to compile your java files, create wars and often even put the .war files onto the tomcats.

Maven is bigger and tries to do a lot more, but it's also rather strict in it's format and quite heavy--but it's quite common these days as well.  Maven can gather all your dependencies automatically which is nice, with ant you still have to download everything yourself.

There are others, but you get the idea.

Response to comment:

I don't use visual studio, but I think it is more limited.  For instance, Eclipse can build all your java files into a jar or execute them directly (in fact, it uses ant internally).  If you wanted to take your visual stuido "Build configuration" and put it into another tool (Perhaps an automated build system like Jenkins) that doesn't rely on visual studio directly, can you do so?

I guess Ant is the way we code our builds--it's portable betweeen many tools.  Visual Studio would be cleaner to "create" your build, but "Exporting" the ability to build would be more difficult (if even possible).

Also ant is portable across operating systems as well as tools.   We can switch from Eclipse to Netbeans to IntelliJ without touching our build toolchain.

How would you completely remove visual studio and replace it with slickedit, emacs or vi (if that was your thing, which I'm sure it's not) without starting over from scratch with your build?

Comment: So I have have been spoiled if I use Visual Studio for C# web apps?

Comment: No, there is a similar tool called Nant for the .Net world, see => http://nant.sourceforge.net/

Comment: The comment I was replying to (the one from Johnny above yours) was for Visual Studio vs ant.  I think the existance of Nant actually answers the question well though--Visual Studio alone isn't a replacement for Ant.

Answer (score 2):

For any web application to work you need to `package` or `build` all your java code with all the libraries into an [web application archive](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnadx.html) to accomplish this task we need to some tool or library to package into the correct format and some of the libraries which can achieve this is
`Apache Ant` and [Apache Maven](http://maven.apache.org/)

There some good discussions about [Ant vs Maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/80622/maven-or-ant) in SO.

Comment: If I'm using hibernate, I thought I could use eclipse to generate my pojo objects with hibernate.  Is this different?

Comment: Eclipse can generate `pojo` objects irrespective of `hibernate`, ok, eclipse and many other ide can generate war and it will work, but assume if you want more customisation while generating war and these things you can do it using ant or maven.

Answer (score 0):

You need ant to build the project. Well you can build project using IDE like eclipse etc. But for production purpose and big projects, it always advisable to some build script like ant. Its a script where you  can customize what you want to build and what not. you can define what is the output should be like war/jar/ear etc

Other alternative is Maven which is very prevalent and standard now a days